# Dynamic Pivot of Email Addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tried to research this, and I am unable to find something quite like it. I have a table that may have entries added many times over as well as deleted. I have no idea how many columns I will need, therefore I need a Dynamic Pivot. All the examples I see use a windows function, but I am pivoting email addresses.

The Table would look something like this:

```
Number | Email
--------------
1      | email1@email.com
1      | email2@email.com
1      | email3@email.com
2      | email4@email.com
2      | email5@email.com
3      | email6@email.com
4      | email7@email.com
4      | email8@email.com
```

I want the table to look like this(when all are included):

```
Number | Email1           | Email2           | Email3           
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | email1@email.com | email2@email.com | email3@email.com
2      | email4@email.com | email5@email.com |
3      | email6@email.com |                  |
4      | email7@email.com | email8@email.com |
```

If Number 1 wasn't included it would look like:

```
Number | Email1           | Email2                     
--------------------------------------------
2      | email4@email.com | email5@email.com 
3      | email6@email.com |
4      | email7@email.com | email8@email.com
```

Thanks for the help!

Here is code to create a mock table:

```
CREATE TABLE #table
(number INT, email VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #table (number, email)
VALUES  (1,'email1@email.com')
       ,(1,'email2@email.com')
       ,(1,'email3@email.com')
       ,(2,'email4@email.com')
       ,(2,'email5@email.com')
       ,(3,'email6@email.com')
       ,(4,'email7@email.com')
       ,(4,'email8@email.com')
```

This is similar to what I have tried, I used count to try and just make it work, but was unable.

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Number)
  FROM (SELECT p.Number FROM #table AS p
  GROUP BY p.Name) AS x;

SELECT @columns

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.number, p.email
   FROM #test p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  Count(email) FOR Name IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create a `RNO` by partition over `Number`. 
The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Number INT, Email VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO #table (Number, Email)
VALUES  (1,'email1@email.com')
       ,(1,'email2@email.com')
       ,(1,'email3@email.com')
       ,(2,'email4@email.com')
       ,(2,'email5@email.com')
       ,(3,'email6@email.com')
       ,(4,'email7@email.com')
       ,(4,'email8@email.com')

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Number, Email) AS [RNO] INTO #temp FROM #table

DECLARE @DynamicCols NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @pvt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @pvt = STUFF(
  (SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + QUOTENAME([RNO]) FROM #temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,N'')

SET @DynamicCols = STUFF(
  (SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + QUOTENAME([RNO]) + ' AS '+ QUOTENAME('Email' + CAST([RNO] AS VARCHAR(MAX))) FROM #temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,N'')


EXEC (N'SELECT [Number],'+ @DynamicCols+'
            FROM #temp tmp
        PIVOT (MAX([Email]) FOR RNO IN('+@pvt+')) AS PIV');
```

Comment: I extrapolated it out for what i needed it for and this appears to work as intended. I have to make several temp tables and join them as there are a few of these pivots I have to do and join it back to the original data with each unique number. I have never done a dynamic pivot and this is perfect. Thank you.